# Given array of unique ints, When iterating through, is it possible to know the "previous closest larger" of already visited in O(1)?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

I define "previous closest larger" (further PCL) as  a number that we already passed with the iteration and that is bigger than current, but as close (on index) as possible.

Given array of unique ints.

I will iterate through the array. At every step I want to know the PCL (of already visited) to current?
Additional space is irrelevant, but preferably the algorithm should not bring any additional time complexity.

e.g. [1, 7, 6, 3, 4, 8, 2, 5, 0]

Implementing pcl(). When reaching 4 I want pcl() to return 6, when reaching 5 it should return 8.
if current is the biggest it could return itself or null, it is irrelevant.

If you could think of algorithms that are worse than O(1) but better than O(n) share them too.

Comment: This really resembles Element Distinctness Problem.

Comment: @amit well the elements are unique

Comment: Yea, and yet, it resembles it. In fact, I believe I can prove this cannot be done under algebraic computation model.

Comment: Oh, wait, maybe I misinterpeted the problem, for 4 - does it indeed need to be 7, or 6? What should be the value when reaching 5?

Comment: @amit My mistake, Of course it is 6. I f you can prove that it is not possible, it would be very valueable for me.

Comment: I am still thinking about it, and anyway it will be limited to algebraic computation model only (so if you could utilize hash somehow, that is not covered by this model, for example).

Comment: "previous larger" may better convey what you're after. "closest" doesn't imply (to me) a search in a single direction, and you don't need "biggest", which would be the max.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever good point

Comment: If somebody can think of algos that are better than O(n) share them too. To have at least something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a stack

At every step compare stack top with current element and remove stack top until it becomes larger - now you know "previous larger".

If stack is empty (or becomes empty) - there is no larger predescessor for current element.

Put current element onto stack.

Stack keeps candidates to be "larger"

Algorithm is linear.

```
a = [1, 7, 6, 3, 4, 8, 2, 5, 0]
st = []
larger = []
for x in a:
    while len(st) > 0 and st[-1] < x:
        st.pop()
    if len(st) > 0:
        larger.append(st[-1])
    else:
        larger.append(None)
    st.append(x)
print(larger)

>>[None, None, 7, 6, 6, None, 8, 8, 5]
```

Comment: This is linear. In my description I said I need better then linear.

Comment: @BitBeats but if you need the previous larger for every element then the average time will be O(1) per element

Comment: @namarsood Then I dont undesrtand the algo. What does the stack have at start? "previous larger" means an element that was already passed that is larger, but as small as possible.

Comment: @BitBeats It is linear to treat **all** array. Average (amortized) time per element is O(1)

Comment: for example we have the array [9,5,3]. As I understood correct your algo will return 9 for 3. It need to return 5 for 3. The integer with the smallest difference

Comment: I missed operation of pushing elements into stack. Added.

Comment: Code added. Note that for 4 result is 6 rather than 7

Comment: @MBo thank you for you effort, but this is not what I am searching for. 
should larger=[None, None, 7, 6, 6, None, 3, 6, 1]

Comment: @BitBeats I answered on your question that says `when reaching 5 it should return 8`. Now you want another condition - so it is worth to make another question?

Comment: Wait, a little bit, I think I have confused myself. need to reunderstand my own Problem one more time

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Sry, I have confused myself before. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Another implementation in c++ for the algorithm suggested by Mbo

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    stack <int> s;

    vector<int> v = {1, 7, 6, 3, 4, 8, 2, 5, 0};

    int i=0;

    while(i<v.size()){

        while(!s.empty() && v[i] >= s.top())
            s.pop();

        if(!s.empty())
            cout<<"previous larger for "<<v[i]<<" : "<<s.top()<<endl;
        

        s.push(v[i]);

        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
previous larger for 6 : 7
previous larger for 3 : 6
previous larger for 4 : 6
previous larger for 2 : 8
previous larger for 5 : 8
previous larger for 0 : 5
```

Comment: As the array is not sorted, so we will have to traverse the array, and complexity is also O(1) in average. We can't have O(logN) if that is what you are expecting

Answer (score 1):

> **Edited to add:** I posted this answer before the question was edited. The original wording was *"... but as small as possible. That means the difference of PCL and current is as small as possible"*. The new wording of the question is *"... but as close (on index) as possible"* which changes the problem. This answer addresses the original question.

You can do this in O(log *n*) time per element with a balanced [binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree): insert the elements one-by-one, and before inserting each element, search the tree recursively for the smallest existing element larger than the target, starting from the root node:

- If the current node's value is less than or equal to the target, then return "None" if there is no right subtree, otherwise recurse on the right subtree.
- Otherwise, the current node's value is greater than the target, so return the current node's value if there is no left subtree, or otherwise recurse on the left subtree and return the result of that recursive call if it is not None, otherwise return the current node's value.

Inserting also takes O(log *n*) time per element, so you process the whole input array in O(*n* log *n*) time.

---

There is certainly no way to do it in O(1) time per element. Suppose you could: then you could iterate through the array to find the PCL of each element, and *backwards* to find the NCL (next closest largest) element. This would allow you to build a hashtable mapping each element to its min(PCL, NCL), i.e. its closest larger element anywhere in the array. This hashtable would be built in O(*n*) time.

Another hashtable mapping each element to its frequency could be built in O(*n*) time, and the minimum element can be found in O(*n*) time. From this, you could build a sorted output array as follows: start from the minimum element, retrieve its frequency from the second hashtable to insert the correct amount of it into the output. Then iteratively retrieve its closest largest element from the hashtable and insert the correct amount of it into the output, taking O(1) time per output element. The whole algorithm would build a sorted output array in O(*n*), but this is certainly impossible; you cannot sort an array of numbers in O(*n*) time.